# How to fill form field with contet in text file?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jakarta-ee

I have a text file with this content for example  :

- ali
- ahmadi

I want to fill this content into a table using ajax or jQuery  .
I don't know how to do this  .I'm new in web application programming.

Answer (score 0):

1. send request to server using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
2. get response
3. fill the form

Comment: like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax)